# Opening dynamic link new window (but not popup) with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to open a link in new window, however the link may contain an additional QueryString which is unfortunately available when the user clicks the link. So even the link is given in the code like:

```
<a href="somepage.aspx">click</a>
```

when the user clicks I want user to go to

```
<a href="somepage.aspx?id=1">click</a>
```

and the "1" value on the above example is calculated when user clicks the link. I am aware I can accomplish this with

```
<script>
function openlink()
{
   var calc_i;
   // do calculations and update calc_i value
   window.open("somepage.aspx?id="+calc_i);
}
</script>
<a onclick="openlink()">click</a>
```

This results in a popup window (which I don't want).
What is your suggestion?

Comment: new window, but not pop up? please explain

Comment: @lbu; by popup i mean "window.open", by new window i mean link with _blank target

Comment: i think he means a modal window

Comment: @joseph, no. window.open opens a non-modal by default. what i want is "a behaviour same as a regular href with _blank target"

Comment: so when you click, you want to do some calculations, put the result in the url, then open that url in the same window? you mention **new window** but **not pop-up**? a pop-up IS a new window. what is a *new window* for you anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
function openlink()
{
    var calc_i;
    // do calculations and update calc_i value
    window.open("somepage.aspx?id="+calc_i, "_blank");
}
```

You can specify the name of the new window, which should be opened in window.open. If you use `_blank` it opens up in a complete new window.

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/BRsjr/5/)

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. TIL. +1

Answer (score 2):

It really would be better to just have the querystring in the link already, it would make far more sense.

You could try appending the code in an onclick event like so.

```
<a href="somepage.aspx" onclick="openlink(this)" target="_blank">Hello</a>

function openlink(anchor){
    var calc_i = 1;
    var page = anchor.getAttribute('href');
    anchor.setAttribute('href',page + '?id=' + calc_i);
}
```

Comment: i selected the other answer, because i am a bit scared of changing the anchor may be blocked by some over-paranoid browser :) but voted your answer too. thanks.

Comment: Setting the href is a simple as: `anchor.href = anchor.href + '?id=' + calc_i;`, no need for get/setAttribute.